# Why theoretical value and experimental value(multisim) of voltage gain in common source amp for T model are different?

Tags: amplifier

[image]

gm is 200μMho and my theoretical value of voltage gain is -1/3.
My experimental value(multisim) of voltage gain is -0.43.
Why they are different?

Answer (score 1):

Because the transconductance of your FET is not exactly defined. Slight variations in the production lead to slight variations in the specifications.

BTW: the unit is not mho, but Siemens (abbreviated with a capital S).